# XML Pasrsing Using Python

Tags: python, xml, rss

```
import csv
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def loadRSS():

    # url of rss feed
    url = 'http://www.hindustantimes.com/rss/topnews/rssfeed.xml'

    # creating HTTP response object from given url
    resp = requests.get(url)

    # saving the xml file
    with open('topnewsfeed.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(resp.content)


    def parseXML(xmlfile):

    # create element tree object
    tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)

    # get root element
    root = tree.getroot()

    # create empty list for news items
    newsitems = []

    # iterate news items
    for item in root.findall('./channel/item'):

    # empty news dictionary
    news = {}

    # iterate child elements of item
    for child in item:

    # special checking for namespace object content:media
    if child.tag == '{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}content':
    news['media'] = child.attrib['url']
    else:
    news[child.tag] = child.text.encode('utf8')

    # append news dictionary to news items list
    newsitems.append(news)

    # return news items list
    return newsitems


    def savetoCSV(newsitems, filename):

    # specifying the fields for csv file
    fields = ['guid', 'title', 'pubDate', 'description', 'link', 'media']

    # writing to csv file
    with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:

    # creating a csv dict writer object
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = fields)

    # writing headers (field names)
    writer.writeheader()

    # writing data rows
    writer.writerows(newsitems)


    def main():
    # load rss from web to update existing xml file
    loadRSS()

    # parse xml file
    newsitems = parseXML('topnewsfeed.xml')

    # store news items in a csv file
    savetoCSV(newsitems, 'topnews.csv')


    if __name__ == "__main__":

    # calling main function
    main()
```

Error in the xml parsing: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'. This is an example of parsing a RSS Feed.
Please Help!

Comment: Post the entire stack trace. Python gave you good debug information, pay it forward!

Comment: Fix the indentations in your code... and cut it down to just the part that is failing. If the problem is at `child.text.encode('utf8')` for instance (just guessing) then much of the code doesn't matter for demonstrating the problem.

Comment: The code seems to expect that all child tags have text... the `NoneType` error should give you a hint that one of your variables is None instead of the expected string.

Comment: @tdelaney it is at child.text.encode('utf8')
the entire stack trace is as:
File "C:/Users/College/Desktop/Python/xmlparse.py", line 85, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/College/Desktop/Python/xmlparse.py", line 76, in main
    newsitems = parseXML('topnewsfeed.xml')
  File "C:/Users/College/Desktop/Python/xmlparse.py", line 44, in parseXML
    news[child.tag] = child.text.encode('utf8')

Comment: @tdelaney okay, thank you but how am i supposed to correct it?

Comment: What do you want to do when there is no text? Check child.text before you try a decode or catch the exception, and do whatever you think is best in that case.